# getting data from a join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have self referential model called `Profile` that is connected through the `Relationship` model.

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user

  has_many :accepted_relationships, class_name: 'Relationship', foreign_key: 'responder_id'
  has_many :followers, through: :accepted_relationships, source: 'initiator'

  has_many :initiated_relationships, class_name: 'Relationship', foreign_key: 'initiator_id'
  has_many :followed_profiles, through: :initiated_relationships, source: 'responder'

  has_many :groups
end

class Relationship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :responder, class_name: 'Profile', foreign_key: 'responder_id'
  belongs_to :initiator, class_name: 'Profile', foreign_key: 'initiator_id'
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile

  has_many :relationships

  attr_accessible :name
end
```

The problem is I don't know how to access data on the join model. If I do something like;

`user.profiles[1].followers[1]`

it will give me the profile I want. I would also like to have something like;

`user.profiles[1].followers[1].assigned_group`

so I could access the group that the relationship belongs to.

Is my design off, or am I overlooking something here?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, Your Group will have many profiles and does your group require relationships, you can have either relationships or profiles in your group or profiles through relationships

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting closer to an answer. I am passing a block to has_many

```
has_many accepted_relationships... do
  def assigned_group
    #code
  end
end
```

I still haven't quite gotten it, but I think this is the route I need to take.